# ItemsControl DataTemplate not binding to underlining data

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having a very difficult time trying to get this to two-way bind to the item in the collection. The strange thing here is that the control shows the label but when I type anything in the text box it doesn't set the underlining value. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryObject.RequiredParameters}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type queryModels:QueryObjectParameter}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Label}"></Label>
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I've tried these different types.

1. `{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} , Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`
2. `{Binding XPath=DataContext.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} , Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`
3. `{Binding XPath=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}} , Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`
4. `{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}} , Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
I have been asked to add a better example to this so I created a very easy example. Note: the underlining model is called, but it doesn't set the model in the ViewModel.

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

      public MainWindowViewModel()
      {
           PersonQuery = new PersonQuery();
           Command = new DelegateCommand(CommandAction);
      }

      private void CommandAction()
      {
           MessageBox.Show(PersonQuery.Parameters.First().ToString());
      }

      public DelegateCommand Command { get; set; }

      public PersonQuery PersonQuery { get; set; }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
 }

 public class Parameter
 {
      public Parameter(string label)
      {
           Label = label;
      }
      public string Label { get; set; }

      public object Value { get; set; }

      public override string ToString()
      {
           return $"{Label}:{Value}";
      }
 }

 public class PersonQuery
 {
      public Parameter[] Parameters => new[] {new Parameter("Test"),};
 }
```

XAML:

```
    <Button Content="Run" Command="{Binding Command}"></Button>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonQuery.Parameters}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parameter}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="{Binding Label}"></Label>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't set the underlining value"?

Comment: it doesn't set the value of the model that is being passed in

Comment: It would be useful if you post a MCVE, including what your `QueryObject` looks like.

Comment: okay, what is MCVE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure, I will add that, just give me a few momments

Comment: I'd recommend your Parameter class implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and PersonQuery should switch to use OservableCollection<Parameter> instead. WPF binding heavily depends on INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example where an `ItemsControl` is used and property update works both ways.

Simple `Data` class:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my `MainWindow` for convenience, but you should really use a ViewModel and do this there.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Data> _dataList = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataList
    {
        get { return _dataList; }
        set
        {
            _dataList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataList");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataList = new ObservableCollection<Data>
        {
            new Data() { Id = 1, Name = "Dan" },
            new Data() { Id = 2, Name = "Julie" }
        };

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

The `XAML` is super simple:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Id}"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

### NOTE:

Check in your code if you have:

1. Implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Use an `ObservableCollection` for your list.

Comment: thank you for this, the crazy thing is that it's calling the setter of the underlining model.

Comment: Isn't that exactly how WPF is designed though? We set `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl` to our `DataList` which is of type `Data`. So the children of `ItemsControl` is aware of the existence of type `Data`, and that it has two properties named `Id` and `Name`. So inside the `DataTemplate` you can directly bind to said properties, and if the mode is two way (btw you don't have to explicitly set it as it's the default) then the changes on `View` will be reflected on `ViewModel`.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The issue is when I create Parameters I do this: `public Parameter[] Parameters => new[] {new Parameter("Test"),}` when i should do this: `public Parameter[] Parameters {get;} = new[] {new Parameter("Test"),}`

Comment: Sweet. Please make the answer accepted if it helped solve your problem.